# SignalR client script runs only in index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm developing an MVC 4 web application and using signalR library to make a real time notification system.
I have a working script that I use in master page called _Layout.cshtml.
here's the script in _Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>


</head>
<body >


    <header dir="rtl">

        <table   align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width:100%;">

            <tr>
                <td style="width:30%; height:40px;" valign="top"><img  src="~/Images/header_logo3.png" /></td>
                <td style="width: 40%;  height: 40px; " valign="top"> <a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'><img class="header_logo" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/header_logo2.png")' /></a></td>
                <td style="width: 30%; height: 40px; " valign="top" ><img  src="~/Images/header_logo4.png" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>



        <h2>Index</h2>
        <span id="mySpanTag"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

            $(function () {
                //Create Hub on Air
                var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;

                //Messages
                $messages = $("#mySpanTag");

                //Client Side Method To Access From Server Side Method
                chat.client.sendMessage = function (msg) {
                    $messages.html(msg);
                }

                $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                    chat.server.sendMessage("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        </script>



    </header>

    <div id="wrapper" dir="rtl">
        <div id="Smenu" class="visible">
            @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "SettingsMenu", new { id = "nir"});}
        </div>
        @RenderSection("JavaScript", false)
        <section>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

the Hub class:

```
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HaifanetMobile.Hubs
{

    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {


        public void SendMessage(string msg)
        {
            Clients.All.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

Everything goes ok and I see the massage method called from the hub class in my page, except that
this script is running only on the index.cshtml (startup page) and not in all the web pages in the project or in a specific one of them. e.g not working and the script is the same as you can see:

```
@model schoolnetMobile.Models.UserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <span id="mySpanTag"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

        $(function () {
            //Create Hub on Air
            var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;

            //Messages
            $messages = $("#mySpanTag");

            //Client Side Method To Access From Server Side Method
            chat.client.sendMessage = function (msg) {
                $messages.html(msg);
            }

            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                chat.server.sendMessage("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <br /><br />

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        <h4>profile: @Model.UserName</h4>
        if (User.Identity.Name == @Model.UserName)
        {
           <br />
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>first name: @Model.FirstName;</li>
                <li>username: @Model.UserName</li>
                <li>schoolname: @Model.SchoolName</li>
                <li>role: @Model.Role</li>
            </ul>
        }
        else
        { 

            <br />
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">

                <li>username: @Model.UserName</li>
                <li>school: @Model.SchoolName</li>
                <li>role: @Model.Role</li>
            </ul>
        }
    }
    else
    { 
      <h4>need to login</h4>
    }
```

Update: I placed the script only if detail.cshtml. Looks like 
there is a problem in this line
var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;
as only the first alert("hi")  pops up and not the second...

```
@model HaifanetMobile.Models.UserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts
{

<script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            //Create Hub on Air
            alert("hi"); 
            var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;
            alert("hi1");
            //Messages
            $messages = $("#messages");
            alert("hi2");
            //Client Side Method To Access From Server Side Method
            chat.client.addMessage = function (frm, msg) {
                $messages.append("<br /><b>" + frm + ":</b>" + msg);
            }
            alert("hi3");
            $("#txtMsg").keypress(function (e) {
                //when enter
                if (e.which == 13) {

                    alert("hi4");
                    //get value of input
                    var input = $(this).val();

                    //send message to "Server Side Method"
                    chat.server.sendMessage("@Session.SessionID", input);

                    //Reset TextBox
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });
            //Hub Starting
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });


</script> 

    }
    <div>Your ID: @Session.SessionID</div>
    <input type="text" id="txtMsg" />
    <div id="messages">
    </div>

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <span id="mySpanTag"></span>


    <br /><br />

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        <h4>user profile: @Model.UserName</h4>
        if (User.Identity.Name == @Model.UserName)
        {
           <br />
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>first name: @Model.FirstName;</li>
                <li>user name: @Model.UserName</li>
                <li>school: @Model.SchoolName</li>
                <li>role: @Model.Role</li>
            </ul>
        }
        else
        { 

            <br />
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">

                <li>username: @Model.UserName</li>
                <li>school: @Model.SchoolName</li>
                <li>role: @Model.Role</li>
            </ul>
        }
    }
    else
    { 
      <h4>Please login</h4>
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the same script in both the pages?

Comment: No, I move it from _Layout to detail.cshtml for testing so there is no duplication, but in one page it works and not in the other...

Comment: change ` $messages = $("#mySpanTag");` to ` $messages = $("#mySpanTag")[0];` and try. :\

Comment: nope :(
still not working

Comment: Close your project and re-open it. Sometimes if you have added the scripts after the page (page using layout) has been added it will not be loaded. This situation of yours is new to me :/ . I hope this works. Also make sure in your entire DOM the id of the elements being used in script are different.

Comment: unfortunately no luck :(

Comment: The following line is included in all your templates (perhaps via _ViewStart), right? `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Also be careful not to include jQuery twice.

I would look at the rendered output of your views and debug from there.

Comment: The js is called but there seems to be a problem. Please look at the update in my original post